# Accessing the feature layers inside a geodatabase using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, file-geodatabase, python-toolbox

In an Python Toolbox I have a parameter that gets the location of a geodatabase `input.gdb` which has several layers of input data.

```
contextual_data_param = arcpy.Parameter(
    name="context",
    displayName="source for contextual data files",
    datatype="GPFile",
    direction="Input",
    parameterType="Optional"
    )
```

From that parameter I would like to access feature layers in the .gdb individually.

Appending layer names using `os.path.join()` hasn't worked because the parameter returns a `geoprocessing value` rather than a string/path.

Is `GPfile` the right datatype to be using?

How can I open a feature layer in a geodatabase using the separate names of the feature layer and the geodatabase?

Comment: A file geodatabase is a `DEWorkspace` class (the contents of which can be accessed via `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()` and `ListTables` and `ListDatasets`).  See the [documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/defining-parameter-data-types-in-a-python-toolbox.htm). I use `os.path.join` exclusively, so I know it works (if you extract the path with `.valueAsText` -- note that the value is `unicode` in Python 2.7),

Comment: thanks, happy to accept as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File geodatabase is a container class which holds feature classes, feature datasets (which group feature classes), and tables. Python Toolbox parameter class for file geodatabase is `DEWorkspace` (which also includes directories which contain shapefiles and Enterprise geodatabase connection files (`.sde`)).

The for a parameter declared like this:

```py
    def getParameterInfo(self):
        contextual_data_param = arcpy.Parameter(
            name="context",
            displayName="source for contextual data files",
            datatype="DEWorkspace",
            direction="Input",
            parameterType="Optional"
        )
        return [contextual_data_param]
```

The `execute` function to exploit the collected data might look like

```py
    def execute(self, parameters, messages):

        cdp  = parameters[0].valueAsText
        arcpy.env.workspace = cdp

        full_fcs = []
        for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
            full_fcs.append(os.path.join(cdp,fc))

        ...
```

The full list of supported toolbox parameters is [documented](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/defining-parameter-data-types-in-a-python-toolbox.htm) online (this is Pro, but Desktop has the same options).
It's not unusual to have to sift through and choose your best option.